# How to combine whereJsonContains and orWhere on an array in the json db structure

Tags: php, json, eloquent

My Json Example Object that is saved in a database field looks like:

```
{
"xyz": {
    "test": [
        {
            "text": "Here comes text", 
            "options": {"aaa": "", "bbb": "", "ccc": "", "ddd": "", "eee": "", "fff": "", "ggg": [7093], "hhh": "true", "iii": ""}
        },
        {
            "text": "Here comes text 2", 
            "options": {"aaa": "", "bbb": "["987", "654"]", "ccc": "", "ddd": "", "eee": "", "fff": "", "ggg": ["1234", "4567"], "hhh": "true", "iii": ""}
        },

    ]
}, 
"options": {
    "name": "abc", 
    "xxx": [366, 193], 
    "yyy": [128], 
    "zzz": [557]
}
```

}

So lets say i have saved this in a field "document" in an table "myTable".

Now i wanna find all entries in myTable that have anywhere under options the reference "193".

I iterate over an config array [xxx, yyy, zzz] and want to query orWhere on each element.

```
foreach($config as $key){
    $query = $query->orWhere("document->options->".$key, $searchId);
}
```

But document field contains a json object and document->options->xxx contains an array of Ids.

The question is how i can build an orWhere Query for this case?

Comment: Do you mean `orWhereJsonContains()`?

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. This helps me with searching the options. But how i can access the xyz object, where i have an array with different number of entries?
For the options i can search like  

`$myquery = $myquery->orWhereJsonContains('document->options->xxx', 193);`  
`$myquery = $myquery->orWhereJsonContains('document->options->yyy', 193);`  

That works fine..  

But how i can access the xyz->test[]->options->bbb?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Jonas ... I am using mysql. i also could switch to maria db, but actually using mysql

Comment: You can query `xyz->test[]->options->bbb` like this: `->whereJsonContains('document->xyz->test', ['options' => ['bbb' => '']])`

Comment: @jonas - Thanks a lot.. This is the solution for the problem...Would like to give an upvote for Jonas, but dont know how.
Thanks to Jonas Staudenmeir.